# Checking Java files for == Error's, not limited to Strings

Tags: java, equals, equality

Many of the standard source code checking tools (PMD, FindBugs, Checkstyles) all implement a "String Equality" rule, where the usage of `==` (or `!=`) when comparing strings can be detected and reported as an error.

I'm looking to write (or configure!) a similar rule that works on a set of other object types in my API.

```
//Want to detect things like:
Instance a = ...;
Instance b = ...;
if ( a == b ) //Error here, not using a.equals(b)
```

Looking at PMD & FindBugs there is no obvious (or easy) way to do this, has anyone come across something like this ?

Cheers,
Ro

Comment: It's worth noting that using == with objects can be a reasonable thing to do. When you want to know if it literally is the same objecg being refered to, not just one that looks the same

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't [CompareObjectsWithEquals](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/design.html#CompareObjectsWithEquals) in PMD work for you?

Comment: Not exactly, that too much ... I need to configure the rule to only consider certain Classes. But Thanks!, that's a great starting point.